# Hibernate confusion - should I use repository or session in spring boot

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Definitely confused here, I use spring boot to create 2 simple classes where the child class has a one-to-many with parent class

I save records using the repository pattern, but when I look up the parent record, I get a lazyinitializationexception for the child records.

Am I supposed to use hibernate session instead of repository?

```
@Autowired  CustomerRepository customerRepository;
@Autowired  ProductRepository productRepository;

Customer bob = new Customer("Bob");
customerRepository.save(bob);
productRepository.save(new Product("p1", 1, bob));
productRepository.save(new Product("p2", 1, bob));

Customer mycustomer = session.findCustomerByName("Bob");

System.out.printf(mycustomer.getProducts().toString());   // generates exception
```

Standard repository interfaces

```
@Repository
public interface CustomerRepository extends JpaRepository<Customer, Long> {
    Customer findCustomerByName(String name);
}

@Repository
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product, Long> {
}
```

Simple entity classes

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "customer")
@Getter @Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Customer {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    public Customer(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Product> products = new ArrayList<>();
```

And

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Product {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "qty")
    private Integer qty;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id")
    private Customer customer;

    public Product(String name, Integer qty, Customer customer) {
        this.name = name;
        this.qty = qty;
        this.customer = customer;
    }
}
```

Not sure if I need to be getting a hibernate session if I use the methods from repository.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

OneToMany is default LAZY and you are accessing collection outside of hibernate session(running transaction). Even the list is empty a select is needed to initialize lazy collection. Persistence cannot know if there are items in collection, unless it checks in DB.

options:

- FetchType.EAGER
- join fetch rels r in your JPQL
- initialize collection inside transaction/session

Another option to avoid Lazy initiliazation exception is using a stream to count objects in order to execute the query to bring the childs.

Comment: I moved all insert code, and the find code into 2 separate methods, each annotated @Transactional  (e.g.  customerRepository.findCustomerByName("Bobbie") )  but now I get the same  lazyInitializationException "could not initialize proxy - no session" ...a code example of what I'm missing would really help!

Comment: Transactional is to revoke any Db alternation if something happens.
Another option is to use JPQL and perform LEFT JOIN FETCH as i said earlier according https://thorben-janssen.com/lazyinitializationexception/